# Hotfixes for a new 2.5.3 website

Tags: control-panel, settings, update

Before starting on a new #eecms website, are there any other hotfixes i need to know of ?!

- **Channel posting privileges being removed from member groups**
  When editing Member Group permissions and pressing save, channel posting privileges are being removed from all other non-Super Admin member groups.
  https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18234
- **Edit date wrong on initial save**
  On initial save the edit_date is set equal to entry_date,
  On next saves edit_date is correctly set to localize->now.
  https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18308

Answer (score 5):

Most of the errors I run into have to do with Safecracker, since I usually build out my stuff in the front-end. I have a rolling fork for it.

- Saferacker_lib.php (Line 1210) 
  http://expressionengine.com/bug_tracker/bug/18233

There is another item I forgot to write down, but it's in the Safecracker API classes that extends the channel entries API.

Answer (score 5):

Yes EE has gone for months without a bug fix release. No this doesn't make any sense. But so long as you're being a Smart Developer and backing up as you go you're not likely to encounter any major issues. Just build the site and search the bug tracker if you run into an issue. In all probability most known bugs won't affect you. If something explodes, which is really unlikely, then roll back to your latest DB, revert your Git repo and be on your way.

Comment: Some bugs are hard to hunt down and can take the better part of an afternoon to sort out. This question is to be prepared beforehand.

Comment: I maintain that you don't need to spend time patching your install before starting development. The time could be better spent on features/polish and, frankly, it's EL's job to patch bugs, not ours. If you _do_ run into an issue then there's already a searchable bug tracker which everyone has access to.

Answer (score 4):

There's also this nasty one that prevents you using {path=...} or {encode=...} tags inside your entries. Hotfix here:

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18239/